# SwiftUI / Move object following a first geometry animation

Tags: swiftui

Can you please help updating the code to move the green image text "One thing is for sure ....." just above its original position only once the first animation has terminated  ?
(for instance just below the "Toggle" text)
Thanks,
Olivier

Can you please help updating the code to move the green image text "One thing is for sure ....." just above its original position only once the first animation  has terminated ?
(for instance just below the "Toggle" text)

```
        import SwiftUI
    
    
    
    struct ContentView : View {
    
        // @EnvironmentObject var showBack: Bool
       @State var showBack = false
        
        var body : some View {
            
            VStack() {
                ContentViewTest()
                Spacer()
                Text(String(self.showBack))
                }
           }
        }
        
    
    struct ContentViewTest : View {
    
          @State var showBack = false
    
          let sample1 = "If you know you have an unpleasant nature and dislike people, this is no obstacle to work."
          let sample2 = "One thing is for sure – a sheep is not a creature of the air."
    
          var body : some View {
    
                let front = CardFace(text: sample1, background: Color.yellow)
                let back = CardFace(text: sample2, background: Color.green)
                let resetBackButton = Button(action: { self.showBack = true }) { Text("Back")}.disabled(showBack == true)
            
                let resetFrontButton = Button(action: { self.showBack = false }) { Text("Front")}.disabled(showBack == false)
            
                let animatedToggle = Button(action: {
                      withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.8)) {
                            self.showBack.toggle()
                      }
                }) { Text("Toggle")}
    
    
                return
                      VStack() {
                            HStack() {
                                  resetFrontButton
                                  Spacer()
                                  animatedToggle
                                  Spacer()
                                  resetBackButton
                            }.padding()
                         Spacer()
                         Spacer()
                         Spacer()
                         Spacer()
                         FlipView(front: front, back: back, showBack: $showBack)
                }
          }
    }
    
    
    struct FlipView<SomeTypeOfViewA : View, SomeTypeOfViewB : View> : View {
    
          var front : SomeTypeOfViewA
          var back : SomeTypeOfViewB
    
          @State private var flipped = false
          @Binding var showBack : Bool
    
          var body: some View {
    
                return VStack {
                      Spacer()
    
                      ZStack() {
                            front.opacity(flipped ? 0.0 : 1.0)
                            back.opacity(flipped ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                      }
                      .modifier(FlipEffect(flipped: $flipped, angle: showBack ? 180 : 0, axis: (x: 1, y: 0)))
                      .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.8)) {
                                  self.showBack.toggle()
                            }
                      }
                      Spacer()
                }
          }
    }
    
    struct CardFace<SomeTypeOfView : View> : View {
          var text : String
          var background: SomeTypeOfView
    
          var body: some View {
                Text(text)
                      .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                      .padding(5).frame(width: 250, height: 150).background(background)
          }
    }
    
    struct FlipEffect: GeometryEffect {
    
          var animatableData: Double {
                get { angle }
                set { angle = newValue }
          }
    
          @Binding var flipped: Bool
          var angle: Double
          let axis: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
    
          func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
    
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.flipped = self.angle >= 90 && self.angle < 270
                }
    
                let tweakedAngle = flipped ? -180 + angle : angle
                let a = CGFloat(Angle(degrees: tweakedAngle).radians)
    
                var transform3d = CATransform3DIdentity;
                transform3d.m34 = -1/max(size.width, size.height)
    
                transform3d = CATransform3DRotate(transform3d, a, axis.x, axis.y, 0)
                transform3d = CATransform3DTranslate(transform3d, -size.width/2.0, -size.height/2.0, 0)
    
                let affineTransform = ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: size.width/2.0, y: size.height / 2.0))
    
                return ProjectionTransform(transform3d).concatenating(affineTransform)
          }
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code to update?

Comment: the code has been added

Comment: @Asperi , I have added the code, have you time to help?